# How not to block UI thread in WinForms application when executing synchronous operation

Tags: c#, winforms, async-await, blocking

I'm writing very simplistic WinForms app for college teachers.
Teacher will be able to send files/folders to student computers (30-35 workstations)
over the network to network share.
I already have working application and it works pretty well and suits all needs, but..

When I try to copy a folder that contains **25 subfolders, and 311 files total 7.22 MB**
I start to see UI freezes and if I click and drag on a window it got to state "Not Responding"
after all work is done UI responsiveness returns.

I tried to use async over sync...
I create `List<Task> tasks` for all 30 computers and await it with `await Task.WhenAll(tasks)`

This is the code to perform directory copy:

```cs
  private async Task CopyDirectoryAsync(string sourceDirectory, string destinationDirectory, string[] directories,
      string[] files, string host, bool isCollectOperation)
  {
      try
      {
         

          if (isCollectOperation)
          {
              directories = Directory.GetDirectories(sourceDirectory, "*", _defaultEnumerationOptions);
              files = Directory.GetFiles(sourceDirectory, "*.*", _defaultEnumerationOptions);
          }

          await CreateDirectoryAsync(destinationDirectory);
          for (var i = 0; i < directories.Length; i++)
          {
              await CreateDirectoryAsync(@$"{destinationDirectory}{directories[i].Replace(sourceDirectory, "")}");
          }

          for (var i = 0; i < files.Length; i++)
          {
              await CopyFileAsync(files[i], $@"{files[i].Replace(sourceDirectory, destinationDirectory)}", null,
                  false);
          }

          SetHostLabelColor(host, Color.Green);
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
          SetHostLabelColor(host, Color.Red);
          await Log(ex);
      }
  }
```

File copy:

```cs
 private async Task CopyFileAsync(string sourceFile, string destinationFile, string host, bool isFileCopy)
 {
     try
     {
        
         await using var sourceStream = new FileStream(
             sourceFile,
             FileMode.Open,
             FileAccess.Read,
             FileShare.Read,
             8192,
             FileOptions.Asynchronous | FileOptions.SequentialScan);
         await using var destinationStream = new FileStream(
             destinationFile,
             FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write,
             FileShare.None,
             8192,
             FileOptions.Asynchronous | FileOptions.SequentialScan);
         await sourceStream.CopyToAsync(destinationStream);
         if (isFileCopy)
         {
             SetHostLabelColor(host, Color.Green);
         }
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         if (!isFileCopy) throw;
         SetHostLabelColor(host, Color.Red);
         await Log(ex);
     }
 }
```

I wrapped Directory.CreateDirectory() with Task.Run()

```cs
 private static async Task CreateDirectoryAsync(string path)
 {
     await Task.Run(() => { Directory.CreateDirectory(path); });
 }
```

So my theory is that since `Directory.CreateDirectory()` is strictly synchronous even I wrapped it in an asynchronous method with `Task.Run()` - it still blocks message queue of WinForms app
I believe the same applies to `Directory.GetDirectories()` and to `Directory.GetFiles()`

So my question is:
Is there a way in WinForms app to offload a synchronous operation in such a manner that it will not block UI thread, and preferably without using `Control.BeginInvoke()`..

It is OK for this CopyDirectory operation to take long time, since it maybe the limitation of SMB/NTFS/WIN32 or whatever.. but why the UI thread get blocked.

**UPD:**
When I hit  Break All in a debugger
it almost always sits in this code

```cs
[LibraryImport("kernel32.dll", EntryPoint = "CreateFileW", SetLastError = true, StringMarshalling = StringMarshalling.Utf16)]
[GeneratedCode("Microsoft.Interop.LibraryImportGenerator", "7.0.8.42427")]
private unsafe static SafeFileHandle CreateFilePrivate(string lpFileName, int dwDesiredAccess, FileShare dwShareMode, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES* lpSecurityAttributes, FileMode dwCreationDisposition, int dwFlagsAndAttributes, IntPtr hTemplateFile)
{
    bool flag = false;
    nint handle = 0;
    SafeFileHandle safeFileHandle = new SafeFileHandle();
    int lastSystemError;
    try
    {
        try
        {
            fixed (char* ptr = &Utf16StringMarshaller.GetPinnableReference(lpFileName))
            {
                void* lpFileName2 = ptr;
                Marshal.SetLastSystemError(0);
/* Always here --> */   handle = __PInvoke((ushort*)lpFileName2, dwDesiredAccess, dwShareMode, lpSecurityAttributes, dwCreationDisposition, dwFlagsAndAttributes, hTemplateFile);
                lastSystemError = Marshal.GetLastSystemError();
            }
        }
        finally
        {
        }
        flag = true;
    }
    finally
    {
        if (flag)
        {
            Marshal.InitHandle(safeFileHandle, handle);
        }
    }
    Marshal.SetLastPInvokeError(lastSystemError);
    return safeFileHandle;
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", EntryPoint = "CreateFileW", ExactSpelling = true)]
    static extern unsafe IntPtr __PInvoke(ushort* lpFileName, int dwDesiredAccess, FileShare dwShareMode, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES* lpSecurityAttributes, FileMode dwCreationDisposition, int dwFlagsAndAttributes, IntPtr hTemplateFile);
}
```

Comment: UI hang is usually because of missing thread/task to handle background process properly. Have you tried using Action<> and CancelToken? 

Also what happens to the speed when you zip the folder structure into a single zip file?

Comment: You can't have your cake and pie too.  If you want to run async than you need to prevent cross-threading and need to using Invoke method.  I've seen this issue lots of times with winForms and I usually solve by running blocking code using an async backgroundworker.

Comment: Use a profiler, or just debugger and "break all" to find out what operation is blocking. `Directory.GetDirectories` may take significant amount of time, and some async methods may lie about being async, or do significant amount of work on the caller thread. In some cases it can be better to just run synchronous calls on a background thread. But you cannot really fix the issue before you know what the problem is, so I would recommend doing some debugging first.

Comment: @JonasH You right, and I did.. When copying one 90MB file to 30 computers UI is not freezing at all, but when I send 1 directory  containing a lot of files  ~300 files 8MB ( all in one directory ) it does freeze.. I tried to change CopyDirectoryAsync - that it creates array of tasks for all files and awaits it with Task.WhenAll(tasks) still freezing UI, but it's wierd.. it's invoking the same function CopyFileAsync

Comment: `Directory.GetDirectories()` and `Directory.GetFiles()` are run synchronously in all Tasks concurrently. You have to move those methods to an async method and await it, as you're doing for the others (the directory creation probably doesn't need to be)

Comment: Also use `EnumerateFIles` so it doesn't actually need to search through them until you enumerate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I start to see UI freezes and if I click and drag on a window it got to state "Not Responding"
> after all work is done UI responsiveness returns.

In asynchronous UI work, this usually means one of two things:

1. The asynchronous work is actually running synchronously.
2. The UI is being bombarded with progress updates to the point where it cannot remain responsive.

I don't see evidence for (2) in your code, so I assume (1) is the culprit. There are [a number of reasons why asynchronous disk I/O may run synchronously on Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows/win32/asynchronous-disk-io-synchronous?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5000058), such as NTFS-level encryption or compression.

Regardless of the reason, there's a simple fix for UI applications: wrap the *entire* directory copy logic in a `Task.Run`. E.g., replace `await CopyDirectoryAsync(...)` with `await Task.Run(() => CopyDirectoryAsync(...))`. Then you can remove other `Task.Run` calls (such as `CreateDirectoryAsync`), and consider replacing the whole `CopyFileAsync` with a simple (and likely faster) call to `File.Copy`.

Comment: Wrapping this way ```  _tasks.Add(Task.Run(() => CopyDirectoryAsync(source, destinationDirectory, directories, files, currentHost, false)));``` actually solved it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: When you see phrases like "the pool of worker threads is limited (currently three on a 16-MB system)" I wonder how up to date that article actually is.